# How to make a user's click to wait for 2 Minutes before the click is processed?

Tags: javascript, button, click, wait

Basically I have a button I click it It goes to next page.

How do I make it so starting from when the page loads it will redirect you in 2 minutes. And if you click it too early a msgbox appears on screen

Comment: It would be in JavaScript. What have you tried 'doe?

Comment: it would need to be done on the client, so _javascript_ is the way to go

Comment: @JaromandaX it should also be checked on the server, so *php* is (also) the way to go

Comment: I don't know what to do at all I am a complete noob at this.

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript. Look out "setTimeout" function on JavaScript and "Disabled" Attribute on HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var timeout = false;
setTimeout(function(){ 
   timeout = true; 
}, 3000);  //wait for 3 seconds
$("#waitForClick").on('click',function(){
  if(!timeout)
   alert("please Wait"); 
  else
    window.location = "Your redirect location";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="waitForClick" > Click me </button>
```

Comment: For some reason when I click the button it doesn't do any of this code

Comment: So it gave alert box didn't redirect and I need the aletbox once the button is click

Comment: The code checks if it has been 3 seconds after this page load and then sets a variable timeout = true.  On click this variable is being checked and allows the user to redirect page when timeout is true

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). I'm sure you'll find many good examples that will be similar to what you want to achieve.

If you'd like to force user to wait for 2 minutes before allowing him to click on the button, possible solution could be also done using [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) + some global variable too. Let's say:

```
window.isButtonXAllowed = false;
setTimeout(function(){ window.isButtonXAllowed = true }, 120000);
```

And in handler handling button's click you'd check for the state of `window.isButtonXAllowed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 2000);
    }
    </script>
```